# problem with check_markup()

Tags: 7

I have a content type called 'microblog', and a default input format for registered users is set to 'Filtered HTML', meanwhile i want to use 'Messaging plain text' format for creating a microblog content.

```
<?php
$content .= check_markup($node->title, $format = 'Messaging plain text', $check = TRUE);
?>
```

But it seems like drupal ignores $format, still when im posting microblog content it uses 'Filtered HTML' format.

PS i'm using http://drupal.org/project/microblog module.
Tried to change in microblog.module on 380 line to 'Messaging plain text' - still no effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this

```
$format = db_result(db_query("SELECT format FROM {filter_formats}
                              WHERE name = 'Messaging plain text';"));
$content .= check_markup($node->title, $format);
```

The problem is that you need to use the format id not the format name.

Comment: Formad ID u mean, when i hover over format settings: admin/settings/filters/4. 4 is id, right?